# Plot stacked barplot with seaborn catplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, catplot

I wonder is it possible to plot stacked bar plot with seaborn catplot.
For example:

```
import seaborn as sns
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
plot = exercise.groupby(['diet'])['kind'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).reset_index(name='percentage%')
g = sns.catplot(x="diet", y="percentage%", hue="kind", data=plot, kind='bar')
```

[image]

I'd like to stack `kind`, but it seems catplot doesn't take 'stacked' parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it using `sns.barplot`, i think the closest you can get is using sns.histplot:

```
import seaborn as sns
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
plot = exercise.groupby(['diet'])['kind'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).reset_index(name='percentage')
g = sns.histplot(x = 'diet' , hue = 'kind',weights= 'percentage',
             multiple = 'stack',data=plot,shrink = 0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: Why compute the value counts and pass them as a weight to histplot instead of letting histplot compute them for you?

Comment: Hi @mwaskom, yes something like `sns.histplot(x = 'diet' , hue = 'kind',multiple = 'stack',data=exercise,shrink = 0.7)` , but no sure how u normalize to percentages with the sns.histplot function...